# php explode something into array, but using values in between

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, explode

I have a string I want to clean up and put into an array so that I can search through it in mysql.

---

```
// Here's one example of what the string might have:
$string1 = "(1) *value1* *value2*; (2) *value3* *value4* *value5*; (3) *value6*";
// And here's another possibility:
$string2 = "*value1* *value2* *value3* *value4*";

// I want to remove all the "(#)" stuff, and explode all the values into an array
// This is what I have so far:
// $string can be like the examples $string1 or $string2

$string_clean = str_replace("* *","",trim(preg_replace("/\((\d)\)/i", "", $string)));
$my_array = explode('*', trim($string_clean, '*'));
```

---

However, this is what I'm getting:

```
Array ( [0] => value1 [1] => [2] => value2 [3] => [4] => value3 [5] => [6] => value4 [7] => [8] => value5 )
```

---

I suppose I could just find a function to remove all empty items from the array, but I'm wondering if there's a more effective way to do this?

Comment: If your values don't contain spaces you could `str_replace()` away `*` and `;`, `preg_repalce()` away `(#)` and then `explode()` on `" "` to get all the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all):

```
preg_match_all('#\*([^*]+)\*#', $string, $matches);
$result = $matches[1];
// $result is array('value1', 'value2', ...)
```

This will find all `*something*` and return the strings between the `*`.

Comment: Thanks man!  I just got a funny result with array within an array though

Comment: Yes, the result is in $matches[1], as I said, not in $matches :-)

Comment: Array ( [0] => 
Array ( 
[0] => *value1* 
[1] => *value2* 
[2] => *value3* 
[3] => *value4* 
[4] => *value5* ) 
[1] => 
Array ( 
[0] => *value1* 
[1] => *value2* 
[2] => *value3* 
[3] => *value4* 
[4] => *value5* ) 
)